# 500 error: Cast to ObjectId failed for value at path \"_id\" for Mongoose model using ResourceJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, typecasting-operator

Following step by step a simple installation of resourcejs as documented in this [MEAN App repo](https://github.com/travist/meanapp), I get the following message, when I access the URL http://localhost:3000/movie/584c6f00cf996a9956784807:

> {"status":500,"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"584dd2842a056e4a648751b5\" at path \"_id\" for model \"movie\"","errors":{}}

POST requests work too, but PUT and DELETE do not.

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var _ = require('lodash');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));

// CORS Support
app.use(function(req, res, next) { 
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/meanapp');
mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {

  // Load the models.
  app.models = require('./models/index');

  var routes = require('./routes');
  var numberOfRoutes = 1;
  _.each(routes, function(controller, route) {
    app.use(route, controller(app, route));
  });

  app.listen(3000);
});
```

**MovieController.js**

```
var Resource = require('resourcejs');
module.exports = function(app, route) {

  // Setup the controller for REST;
  Resource(app, '', route, app.models.movie).rest();

  // Return middleware.
  return function(req, res, next) {
    next();
  };
};
```

The Movie model looks just like [this](https://github.com/travist/meanapp/blob/resourcejs/server/models/Movie.js), and is being served [this way](https://github.com/travist/meanapp/blob/resourcejs/server/models/index.js).

My point of interest is that **[ResourceJS](https://github.com/travist/resourcejs/)** has this following code, which seems to not be able to parse correctly an ID into a MongoDB ObjectID:

```
/**
 * Register the GET method for this resource.
 */
get: function(options) {
    (…)
    var search = {'_id': req.params[this.name + 'Id']}; 
    (…)
}
```

What could possibly be messing this up?

**Stats**
Windows 10 — 64-bit OS, x64-based processor
MongoDB v3.2.7, 64-bit
NodeJS v4.4.7
Mongoose v4.7.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because mongoose wants `ObjectId` but You're passing `string` as `_id`, so You should typecast it.

Try this:

```
var 
  mongoose = require('mongoose');
  ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

/**
 * Register the GET method for this resource.
 */
get: function(options) {
    (…)
    var param = req.param[this.name + 'Id'];
    var search = {'_id': new ObjectId(param)}; 
    (…)
}
```

If You need universal solution that works with any version of Mongoose and Mongo just define `_id` field as string and use `uuid.v4` to generate unique values:

```
var uuid = require('uuid');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Create the MovieSchema.
var MovieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { 
      type: String, 
      index: { unique: true }, 
      default: uuid.v4 
    },
    title: {
       type: String,
       required: true
    },
    url: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
 });

 // Export the model.
 module.exports = mongoose.model('movie', MovieSchema);
```

So in this case Your ResourceJS will stay as before and work properly:

```
get: function(options) {
    (…)
    var search = {'_id': req.param[this.name + 'Id']}; 
    (…)
}
```

P.S. don't forget to install uuid package:

```
npm i --save uuid
```

Comment: Hi! Where would you normally add these statements?

Comment: Wait nevermind I think you mean in ResourceJS right?

Comment: ResourceJS just simplifies REST-ing of mongoose model, so: YES

Comment: seems like version problems between resourcejs and mongoose, cuz express provides string typed param, and resourcejs uses it as-is. but mongoose seems to be strict for `_id` types.

Comment: Typecasting it as suggested returns the following error: **{"status":404,"errors":["Resource not found"]}**. I've posted an issue on this on the GitHub page for ResourceJS too—you might be right that it's a version problem.

Comment: this is great, I made new entries in MongoDB with these new Id's, and it worked. I appreciate your advice and I am glad I do not have to edit the resourceJS library to make my app work again. I have alerted them though about this problem here (https://github.com/travist/resourcejs/issues/61), and will be sharing your answer.